# Python beginner - SSH and User Input question

Tags: python, ssh

I got a script working that allows me to log into a device and then dump the output to a text file. That is great.  I need to be able to do this for multiple devices.  So what I am trying to do is this.  I run the script and it asks me to Enter the IP.  I enter the IP, it logs in and then dumps the output to the file but I can't seem to pass the input to rest of the script.

Also quick request is if someone can guide me but don't solve the problem for me this way I can learn better.  Thank you.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
ipaddr = input('Type IP:')

device(I've tried net_connect also) =  ConnectHandler(ip = 'ipaddr',
                        port = 22,
                        username = 'admin',
                        password = 'mypassword',
                        device_type = 'cisco_wlc_ssh')

net_connect.find_prompt()
'(Cisco Controller) >'
output = net_connect.send_command('show ap summary')
print(output)
net_connect.disconnect()
```

Comment: `ipaddr` is already a string. If you print it, it might print as `127.0.0.1`. But you are putting quotes around it as in `ip = 'ipaddr'`. If you print `'ipaddr'`, what would you get?

Comment: You mean instead of doing print(output) do print(ipaddr)?  But I want to print the output as defined "show ap summary".

My issue is that SSH to the device is not working.

Comment: Not at all. You wanted *hints* not answers. I was trying to make the point that if you were to print `'ipaddr'` you would see `ipaddr` and not `127.0.01`. In other words you need to remove the quotes: `ConnectHandler(ip = ipaddr`. But I suppose I was being too subtle.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean, my apologies still trying to get the hang on it but I know exactly what you mean now.  You are awesome thank you so much.  I have it working now.  I can SSH into my device, run the command and display it and/or redirect the output to the file. So excited my first script.  Thanks so much again.